# Get Error 3075 Data type mismatch in criteria expression

Tags: vba, ms-access

i get

> Error 3075 Data type mismatch in criteria expression

but i no able left it

what is the problem???

but DateCutting is Integer Type

```
Dim strCriteria, task As String
strCriteria = "([DateCutting]>= #'" & Me.txtfrom & "'# And [DateCutting]<=#'" & Me.txtto & "')#"
task = "select * from Cutting where [DateCutting]>= '" & strCriteria & "'"

DoCmd.ApplyFilter task
```

Comment: on which line does the error occur?

Comment: on DoCmd.ApplyFilter task  (but DateCutting is Integer Type)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change DateCutting to **DateTime** and adjust your criteria:

```vb
Dim strCriteria As String

strCriteria = "[DateCutting] >= #" & Format(Me.txtfrom, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "# And [DateCutting] <= #" & Format(Me.txtto, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#"

DoCmd.ApplyFilter strCriteria
```

To find a number:

```
strCriteria = "[Number] = " & Me.txtNumber & ""
```

as text:

```
strCriteria = "[TextNumber] = '" & Me.txtNumber & "'"
```

Comment: with Number Type is no possible?

Comment: Perhaps, but not simple. Depends on how you use numbers for dates. There can be no reason for this other than to make it harder for yourself.

Comment: how can i search number type field (in table) by textBox in forms? for example if i have "numUnit" field in Integer Type, how can i search it on textBox in forms?

Comment: See extended answer, please.

Comment: task = "select * from Cutting where [DateCutting]= #'" & Me.txtfrom.Value & "'# "

Comment: Syntax Error in data in query

Comment: Then your "numbers" are text. See edited answer, please.

Comment: Great! Then please mark as answered, if you feel so.

Answer (score 0):

Try
`Dim strCriteria as String`

`dim task As String`

Comment: this shouldn't be the problem as strCriteria will be variant/string in this case.